# Можно ли переоткрыть вопрос

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Вопрос [Как конвертировать текст в формулу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1308389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83)

Причина закрытия не соответствует содержимому вопроса. Причем вопрос корректный. Качественный.

Его можно переоткрыть?

Comment: Переоткрытие выполняется голосованием (если верно понимаю, оно доступно участникам с 3к+ репутации). То заявление что вопрос по ссылке качественный - весьма спорно: ему не хватает как минимум конкретизации проблемы (что пробовалось, что не получается) и приемлемых путей ее решения (преобразовать можно как вручную, так и _может быть_ и аппскриптом)... другими словами, сейчас вопрос подразумевает ответы "береш и преобразуеш", и это явно не гуд.

Comment: _«Причина закрытия не соответствует содержимому вопроса.»_ - а такое тут повсеместно встречается, это да. Но как повлиять на такую проблему?.. вроде бы никак. Если сообществу что-то можно объяснить в уточняющем комментарии / правкой, то представители власти часто лепят причины закрытия совершенно рандомно (например,  "увидел знакомое слово == дубликат!", а в суть проблемы вникать кагбэ и незачем).

Comment: @yar85, я не смог переоткрытие. Возможно, надо чуть больше 3k или подождать сутки после прохождения порога 3k. С остальным согласен.

Comment: Ну, тут опять же не очень радужно все :) Скажу по личному опыту (который может оказаться ислючением, поэтому прошу не принимать на веру, а отнестись критически) - даже если бы получилось запустить голосование на переоткрытие, то в как минимум в некоторых случаях это имеет ровно **нулевой** эффект: вот в течение месяца безуспешно бьюсь за добавление в базу ответа на уникальный вопрос ошибочно закрытый дубликатом. Судя по счетчику, поддержку сообщества голосование находит, но затем бац, и оно пропадает (раньше срока истечения) - хз почему... может баг, а может кто-то вручную отменяет из очереди.

Comment: Помимо ручного запуска голосования на переоткрытие, обнаружил в справке еще один путь: [_«Система автоматически отправляет вопросы отредактированные в течении 5 дней после закрытия в очередь на повторное открытие.»_](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). В действии подобного не видел, но не особо наблюдал, конечно (следил только за собственными ручными запусками).

Comment: @yar85 [любопытство] какой вопрос ты хочешь переоткрыть?

Comment: @nörbörnën, вообще несколько хочу переоткрыть (точнее, хотел - уже сдался), а последним был [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1295638/288409), где мы с тобой участвовали в комментах. Там сообщество проигнорировало две трети от сути вопроса зацепившись за многострадальный `this`, хотя возможно успешное решение через композицию объекта (и это не только прямым образом ответило бы именно на заданный вопрос о вызове в момент создания, но и позволило бы обойти сложности с контекстом).

Comment: @nörbörnën, то есть, этот вопрос ничем не примечателен, он просто стал лично последней каплей после всех моих попыткок переоткрытия с 2018. Думаю что случаев таких закрытий гораздо больше чем мы можем видеть при обычной деятельности на ruSO, и сайт много уникальных вопросов-ответов теряет (имхо, при уникальности задачи/проблемы и потенциальной пользе ответов, нужно делать небольшую поблажку в отношении качества вопросов - ради устранения "пробелов" в базе знаний... и механическое закрытие "лишь бы причина была" просто не учитывает интересы сообщества, а именно, возможность найти ответы).

Comment: @yar85 мне кажется ты не верно понял вопрос, там же речь о применении  Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (и по коду, и по заголовку вопроса), а это не соотвествует тому, что ты предлагаешь в комментарии. я бы посоучаствовал в твоём движняке, но, имхо, вопрос не значимый, дико [дубликатный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544894/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-javascript) и имеющий достойный ответ от Игор-а (один из голосов - мой)

Comment: @nörbörnën, способ описания функции - вопросом не определен (я не спорю с выводом, а объясняю что переходы на "ты не понял" в данном случае менее логичны чем обращение к фактам). Если другой участник будет искать ответ на тот же вопрос "Можно ли создать самовызывающиеся методы объекта?", то увидит только то как сообщество придралось к примеру в вопросе, и ответ без самовызова... но не увидит ответа на **заданный** вопрос - и **именно это** является критическим недостатком подхода "искать поводы закрыть"... вместо попытки разобраться в вопросе / обеспечить полноту знаний к которой стремится SO.

Comment: @yar85 я понял ход твоих мыслей и вывод про значимость проблемы и ничтожность неудачного примера. могу предложить компромис - добавить ответ в существующий незакрытый вопрос, [напр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/289003/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0). а 'наш' вопрос попросим перезакрыть как дубликат предлагаемого

Comment: @nörbörnën, но как этот компромисс повлияет на общую проблему которую я тут по неосторожности затронул? Вопросы как закрывались "лишь бы была причина", без попытки хоть немножко вникнуть в суть - так и будут закрываться (один ответ, неважно чей, этого не изменит: один ответ это песчинка). Наверное, стоит пояснить отдельно, что дело вовсе не в какой-то боли душевной за понравившиеся вопросики - дело в том, что на SO есть вредные модели поведения, противоречащие цели ресурса... и о которых даже говорить нельзя без риска быть забросанным камнями. Я неправ - ради бога! Но это кого-то оправдывает?

Comment: @nörbörnën, вообще, мы все равно ничего не добьемся этим обсуждением. Моей целью в данной ветке комментов было лишь предупредить ТСа что "от голосования за переоткрытие ждать чудес не стоит" и что закрытия по "рандомной" причине являются здесь абсолютно нормальным явлением, к которому надо просто привыкнуть (принять как данность). Эта цель достигнута, на том и предлагаю закончить, если уже все сказано. Но дополнения приветствуются, конечно (как и конструктивная критика).

Comment: @yar85 просто чтоб объясниться: я не хотел тебя критиковать; зови если нужно что-то переоткрыть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум, у него совершенно нерелевантные метки. Хотя сам вопрос нормальный.